# JavaFX problems switch scenes

Tags: javafx, scene, stage

I have got the following problem:

I am trying to switch between two scenes within one stage. Basics. But it does not work how it is supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
public class Controller {

    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private Scene sceneLogin, sceneRegister;
    private Pane loginPane, registerPane;

    public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        try {
            loginPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loginform.fxml"));
            sceneLogin = new Scene(loginPane, 280, 353);
            stage.setScene(sceneLogin);
            stage.setTitle("Authentification");
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void register(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        try {
            registerPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("registerform.fxml"));
            sceneRegister = new Scene(registerPane, 280, 353);
            stage.setScene(sceneRegister);
            stage.setTitle("Registration");
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Now: It should switch to the second scene as soon as I click a button within the Login Form. But instead, it opens a new window on top of the login form.

Thanks in advance.

--- Some more code ---

MAIN CLASS:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // add sample.fxml as main FXML file for primaryStage
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("SecureTalk V1.0");

    // create primaryScene and add style.css as stylesheet for primaryScene
    Scene primaryScene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
    primaryScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    // set icon for primaryStage
    Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);

    // setScene and resizable false
    primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();

    // Check if admin in a group which requires new vigenere phrase

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't really posted hte code that shows what's going on, but it looks like both of your controllers are from the same `Controller` class. Each controller creates a new stage (`private Stage stage = new Stage();`). So the `stage` field for the controller for the login form is a different stage than the `stage` field for the controller for the register form.

Comment: https://github.com/rogerschneiter/SecureTalk

That is the complete project. I really appreciate your help! I am new to JavaFX btw...

Comment: You really need to post enough code in the question for it to be answerable. Links may go bad, which renders and question/answer unusable for other users (defeating the entire point of posting here in the first place).

Comment: So should I post the code here? Or is this simply a nice tip (thx) for my next post?

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include enough for the question to be answered. Right now we can't tell which fxml file this is the controller for, when these methods are invoked, etc. The best approach is to create - from scratch - a [MCVE] that is a complete executable example and *just enough* code to demonstrate the problem (and no more code than that).

Comment: I can't include the FXML because it says: Not correctly formatted code...

Could please visit GitHub? Otherwise I need to search somewhere else.

Comment: I can look at github, but answering without the code in the question potentially only helps you and no one else, so I'm not particularly inclined to invest time if it's only of assistance to a single person. (Just cost-benefit, etc.). But you should be able to post FXML: check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: i will try to post it again then. But most early tomorrow. I hope you find a solution